# SQL Server not returning custom letters to php

Tags: php, sql-server

I got some troubles while I'm trying to get the original NickName of my players from the SQL Server to PHP.

This is from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
UserID      NickName
46          GM
2000001     GM2
2009594     ™
```

After I pull from PHP, NickName ™ is returning as **????????????�**

How can I convert to exactly as SQL Server?

```
$serverConnect = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server={$ip};Database={$db}; Uid={$user};Pwd={$pass};");
$serverConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$serverConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$nicks = $serverConnect->query("
   SELECT UserID, NickName 
   FROM Sys_Users_Detail 
   WHERE UserName = '$me'
")->fetchAll();

echo $nicks[2]['NickName'];
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 14.

Comment: You need to show your PHP code. How are you viewing the data to see that its stored correctly?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the code. I've edited that.

Comment: Specify the SQL name and version you are using.

Comment: As I asked above "How are you viewing the data to see that its stored correctly?"

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Comment: @Thiago What is the data type of the `NickName` column?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set nickname charset to utf-8

`$serverConnect->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NickName 'utf8'");`

Comment: I'm not using MySQL. This command doesn't work to MSSQL. Thank you.